# Is it recommended to have redundant foreign key columns?

Tags: foreign-key

Imagine I have the models `A`, `B`, `C` e `D`, where `A` have many `B`s, `B` have many `C`s and `C` have many`D`s:

### Without redundance

```
A
|  id | ... |
------------
| ... | ... |

B
|  id | a_id | ... |
--------------------
| ... |  ... | ... |

C
|  id | b_id | ... |
--------------------
| ... |  ... | ... |

D
|  id | c_id | ... |
--------------------
| ... |  ... | ... |
```

---

Would be recommended to have more columns in `C` e `D` with the reference to `A` and `B`?

### With redundance

```
C
|  id | a_id | b_id | ... |
---------------------------
| ... |  ... |  ... | ... |

D
|  id | a_id | b_id | c_id | ... |
----------------------------------
| ... |  ... |  ... |  ... | ... |
```

It's a redundance, but I usually do this to make simpler queries, I can make less `JOIN`s. I think it probably have better performance too.

Is it recommended? (At least when the columns are immutables) Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I can find no fault with adding columns to tables that meet the requirements of your system.

It may in fact make some queries much faster to have the "redundant" columns present.  Take this example, which is pretty contrived, where you want to get a list of parents, and the names of the schools their children attend.  The first example, where parents are not linked directly to schools:

```
SELECT p.ParentName
    , s.SchoolName
FROM dbo.Schools s
    INNER JOIN dbo.Children c on s.School_ID = c.School_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Parents p ON c.Parent_ID = p.Parent_ID;
```

Versus the query where Parents are linked to schools, even though the link is "redundant" since each parents child already has the link:

```
SELECT p.ParentName
    , s.SchoolName
FROM dbo.Schools s
    INNER JOIN dbo.Parents ON s.School_ID = p.School_ID
```

Clearly, you'd want to do the second variant because (a) it's less complicated to understand the intent, and (b) SQL Server has to do less work, which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553231/storing-redundant-foreign-keys-to-avoid-joins

For @max-vernon 's answer, it's true that the first sql is more than the second, but not too much. I prefer the first one. So:

```
    // you have D, and want to get A, then:
    let d = D();
    let c = select C.* from C where C.id=d.c_id;
    let b = select B.* from B where B.id=c.b_id;
    let a = select A.* from A where A.id=b.a_id;
    // or
    let d = D();
    let a = select A.* from A
                right join B on A.id=B.a_id
                right join C on B.id=C.b_id
                right join D on C.id=D.c_id
                where D.id=d.id;

    // you have A, and want to get Ds, then:
    let a = A();
    let Bs = select B.* from B where B.a_id=a.id;
    let Cs = select C.* from C where C.b_id in Bs.map(b => b.id);
    let Ds = select D.* from D where D.c_id in Cs.map(c => c.id);
    // or
    let a = A();
    let Ds = select D.* from D
                left join C on C.id=D.c_id
                left join B on B.id=C.b_id
                left join A on A.id=B.a_id
                where A.id=a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called [denormalization](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Denormalization). Even though it is okay to do this, you should be careful when to apply it.

You should think about which queries are normal for your product, and which are not. If you are denormalizing because of a frequent query then it is alright. If you have a query that without denormalization you need to do 3-4 joins to get the data, then denormalizing will be worth it.

In most cases you don't need this, keeping your database [normalized](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Database_normalization) is the best practice.